# Mysql result from SELECT IF in INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I want to get data from two tables. from the first table I need all names which are not the name of the logged-in user but the name of the logged-in user must be in one of those two columns. I want to use that result to get the name of photos from the second table for each name given from the first table.

```
 table 1 names
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | name1   | name2    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
1  | john    | lea      |<- i need lea because john is in one of those two columns
-------------------------
2  | peter   | john     |<- i need peter because john is in one of those two columns
-------------------------
3  | mark    | paola    |<- no john here so query should ignore
__________________________

table 2 users
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | name    | photo    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
1  | lea     | la.jpg   |<- I want to use lea given with SELECT IF to get name of photo
-------------------------
2  | peter   | pt.jpg   |<- I want to use peter given with SELECT IF to get name of photo
-------------------------
2  | mark    | mk.jpg   |<- no match from SELECT IF so query should ignore
-------------------------
```

My SELECT IF or CONCAT works fine but when i try to use it with INNER JOIN there is no results at all. My codes:

```
$username = 'john';
$sql = "SELECT IF( name1 = '$username', name2, name1 ) AS otheruser
FROM names
WHERE name1 = '$username' OR name2 = '$username'";
```

This code above works fine. Now i am trying to add another table in query with INNER JOIN. It is obvious that INNER JOIN part of code does not get ***otheruser*** result so output is ***"no results"***.

My attempt looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT IF(names.name1 = '$username', names.name2, names.name1) AS otheruser, users.photo
FROM names
INNER JOIN users ON users.name = 'otheruser'
WHERE names.name1 = '$username' OR names.name2 = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$names = $row['otheruser'];
$photos = $row['photo'];
}
} else {echo "no results";}
```

Comment: You have `NNER JOIN users ON users.name = 'otheruser'` is that a copy typo or you're indeed missing an `I` in that `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: It was a copy typo. Thank you.

Comment: When you say 'table', do you mean 'column'?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will correct text now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often like the `COALESCE` function in these cases, but either works.

Try these commands and check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e61e9/7).

```
SELECT IF (name1 = 'john', name2, name1) FROM names WHERE name1 = 'john' or name2='john';

SELECT COALESCE (IF (name1 = 'john', null, name1), IF (name2 = 'john', null, name2)) FROM names WHERE 'john' IN (name1, name2);

SELECT u.username as otheruser, u.photo FROM users u
INNER JOIN names n 
    ON u.username = COALESCE(IF (name1 = 'john', null, name1), IF (name2 = 'john', null, name2))
WHERE 'john' IN (n.name1, n.name2);
```

Comment: Extremely useful for understanding this a bit complicated query. Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the alias name in where condition (the SQL parser evaluates the `select` after the `where condition` so it does not know the select alias  you are using) you should repeat the code

```
"SELECT IF(names.name1 = '$username', names.name2, names.name1) AS otheruser, users.photo
  FROM names
  INNER JOIN users ON users.name = IF(names.name1 = '$username', names.name2, names.name1)
  WHERE names.name1 = '$username' OR names.name2 = '$username'";
```